# I can't get my program to print my text file vertically

Tags: python

I made a text file:

```
52 57 63 69 71 78 82 84 95 96
```

I need to print it vertically with the corresponding numbers, including the sum of it all but I only came up with this:

```
with open("numbers.txt", "r") as f:
    a = [int(n) for line in f.readlines() for n in line.split()]
    print a
    print("\n")

with open("numbers.txt", "r") as f:
    for l in f:
        print(sum([int(a) for a in l.split()]))
```

Comment: What exactly do you want shorter? Please specify your question.

Comment: sorry for that XD
i just need a code that'll meet the conditions 
but if it's shorter then it's better

but i'll take what i can get

Comment: Is your text a line with 10 numbers as you indicate above ? Could you explain better how your text file is ? What do you mean with 'including the code'

Comment: yes, it is. the text file is just like that and i need it to print vertically as long with the answer

Comment: do you want something as https://eval.in/931403

Comment: @splash58 yes that's exactly what I need but it needs to come from the file: 'numbers.txt'. as in, the entered numbers from the txt file is what the program prints

Comment: @yaddi03 i've written code in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few changes in your code:

```
with open("numbers.txt", "r") as f:
    a = [int(n) for line in f.readlines() for n in line.split()]
    for i in a:
        print(i)
    print("Sum: ", sum(a))
```

Output:

```
69
71
78
82
84
95
96
Sum:  747
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Try this:

```
with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as fl:
    text = fl.read()

numbers = [int(n) for n in text.split()]

answer = sum(numbers)

for n in numbers:
    print(n)
print(answer)
```

this produces:

```
52
57
63
69
71
78
82
84
95
96
747
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read a file twice

```
with open("numbers.txt", "r") as f:
  for line in f:
    a = line().split()
    for x in a
        print(x)
    print(sum(int(x) for x in a))
```

Comment: `list` has no attribute `split` :)

Comment: @srig your python is terrible :)

Comment: I knew it must be a typo.

Comment: `f` is already an iterable, you could just do `for line in f`.

Comment: A little more, and I'll learn how to program on Python :)

Answer (score 0):

If the text file has just one line, you could read it with `f.readline()`, like so:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    nums = [int(n) for n in f.readline().split()]

for num in nums:
    print(num)

print()
print(sum(nums))

52
57
63
69
71
78
82
84
95
96

747
>>>
```